# Min requirement to run java class file?

Tags: java

Please tell me the minimum things required for me to run the java class file in windows server 2008 R2

Comment: Depends on the class. At a bare minimum, you need some kind of Java virtual machine. You may also need some library classes that do not come with that virtual machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For plain execution you only need a JRE (Java Runtime Environment). If you want to compile some code you need a JDK(Java Developer Kit). The JDK includes the JRE.

You can get both at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html

Comment: I got compiled class. @Udo Held.

Comment: You only need a JRE then. If you want to try things yourself get the JDK, because it includes the runtime as well.

Comment: Yes i got jdk in my Workstation, i want to run a compiled code in my remote server which doesnt have Java. Thanks for your kind answer. @Udo Held

Comment: You need - on the running mashine - a jre! So you will have to install the jre on your server. Shouldn't be a big thing anyway....